# PowerDNS Recursor for Reverse Zones

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos, powerdns

I'm trying to deploy some PowerDNS servers as an internal DNS host, and I've got the recursor working, and the authoritative working, but the only thing I don't have functional is the reverse lookups. The system is configured to run in the Native setup, with MySQL as the backend.

The Recursor and the Authoritative are running on the same box. Recursor is listening on udp/53, and is set to forward requests for the appropriate domains to the authoritative running on udp/5300. I have a forward setup for the internal company name (internal.corp as the example below), so the A Records, CNAMES, etc., all work as appropriate. The problem I run into is the reverse zones.

I've tried doing:

```
forward-zones+=139.10.in-addr.arpa=127.0.0.1:5300

forward-zones+=0.139.10.in-addr.arpa=127.0.0.1:5300

forward-zones+=0.0.139.10.in-addr.arpa=127.0.0.1:5300
```

Hell, I even tried a specific entry:

```
forward-zones+=10.0.139.10.in-addr.arpa=127.0.0.1:5300
```

And no joy. So, if anyone has a suggestion on how I should poke it, I'd appreciate it!

Configs below:

```
#power dns authoritative
launch=gmysql
gmysql-host=127.0.0.1
gmysql-user=root
gmysql-dbname=pdns
gmysql-password=thisismysuperawesomepassword
webserver=yes
webserver-address=0.0.0.0
api=yes
api-key=changeme
local-ipv6=
local-address=127.0.0.1
local-port=5300


--------
#powerdns recursor
setgid=pdns-recursor
setuid=pdns-recursor
local-address=0.0.0.0
webserver=yes
webserver-port=8082
api-key=changeme
forward-zones=example.com=127.0.0.1:5300
forward-zones+=internal.corp=127.0.0.1:5300
```

Comment: The included config for pdns-rec does not have any forward-zones entries for reverse zones at all. Considering that you went to some lengths discussing these earlier, I find this strange. Also, I would suggest that you not only include the config that you expect to work, but also include dig output that shows off the problem (maybe querying both pdns-rec as well as querying pdns-auth directly).

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist, I had those originally (hence the added lines below), but removed them because they just weren't working. But I'll run some digs against it tomorrow morning and see what I can find out about how the verbose queries respond and include that in the original post.

Comment: Alright, just make sure you put the relevant forward-zones back before testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have similar setup. Auth and recurosor 4.2.x version
Forward zone (example.com) and reverse zone (in-addr.apra) defined on authoritative server. What helped me was adding `serve-rfc1918=no` on recursor's config. Thus recursor actually forwards reverse requests to authoritative server.

Recursor's related config:

```
forward-zones=example.com=127.0.0.1:5300, in-addr.arpa=127.0.0.1:5300
serve-rfc1918=no
```

Comment: just enabling rfc1918 fixed my issue